# Amdgpu-pro 17.50 underclocking on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: overclocking, amdgpu-pro

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 and the current driver on my rx 580 is amdgpu 17.50. I want to overclock memory clock of my gpu from 2000 to 2100(that was easy) and underclock the core clock from 1411 to 1150(the hard part). Since there is no more aticonfig tool and the /sys/class/drm/card*/device/pp_mclk_od and pp_sclk_od does not accept negative values I have no idea how to do it. Can anyone help me please?